# Cauchy Sequences Related-ness

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in Q, the rationals.  For n an element of the Natural Numbers, Let $b_n$ = $a_{n^2}$  Prove that ($a_n$) ~ ($b_n$).

I'm not really sure where to start.
I believe that if ($a_n$) ~ ($b_n$), then $a_n->c$ and $b_n->k$, where c=k, then given some value of $\epsilon$, there should be some value of N>0 such that $-\epsilon < a_N - c < \epsilon$.  And then because N>0 and an integer, $N^2 >= N$, it should also converge to the same value.

Comment: Sorry, yes they are Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 0):

This assertion is false in the special case where you take on $\mathbb{Q}$ the metric $d(p,q)=|\arctan(p)-\arctan(q)|.$ Indeed for $n\in\mathbb{N}^*, $take $a_n=n\in\mathbb{Q}.$ The sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ is Cauchy for $d,$ you get $b_n=a_{n^2}=n^2$ and
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\neq1.$$

Comment: By the title it seems OP is talking specifically about Cauchy sequences, and neither of the sequences you have mentioned are Cauchy.

Comment: @ASKASK : indeed, peraphs we can say that it is a Cauchy sequence for $d(x,y)=|arctan(x)-arctan(y)|$ ?

Comment: I think, since OP has not specified that any metric can be used, we should assume the standard metric

Comment: @ASKASK : Right. Should I edit my answer with the $arctan$ metric giving an idea, or just delete it ?

Comment: Maybe just specify that this answer does not work in the standard metric but does work in some metrics, so that in case OP's question really is talking about Cauchy sequences with any metrics, he can benefit from this answer. I also find this answer interesting so it does no harm to leave it up for others to stumble upon.

Comment: @ASKASK : I did it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much you already know. This theorem is rather trivial if you know the right theorems. Firstly, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both Cauchy sequences, so therefore they converge. Furthermore, $b_n$ is a subsequence of $a_n$, and since $a_n$ converges to a value, all of its subsequences must also converge to that same value.

Something tells me that the last statement is one that you haven't learned yet, but in any case, your work on the topic is *almost* there. Noticing that n^2>n is a crucial step... Now how can we use that in the definition of convergent/Cauchy sequences?

Comment: So $b_n$ is a Cauchy sequence because it is a subsequence of $a_n$.  Then for every epsilon $\epsilon$, there is some N such that if n>N, then $-\epsilon < a_n - c < \epsilon$.  And $-\epsilon < a_{n^2} - c < \epsilon$ because $n^2$ will also be >N because n was, and we know that $b_n = a_{n^2}$, so it converges to the same value.  Is that basically the proof or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep that's basically the proof